# How to hide spinner on the basis of text entered in edittext box?

Tags: android-edittext, hide, spinner, conditional-statements

M sorry for wrong English. I want to hide the spinner on the basis of text entered in the edit Text box and not on some click event. This means spinner hiding condition should be checked on the basis of Edit Text value.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Used TextWatcher  class to have a check on the text that is being entered in the edittext. And then have used the method to check ds

```
private  void checkFieldsForEmptyValues()
{

    Spinner =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.site_spinner1);
    String s1 = edit1.getText().toString();
    String s2 = edit2.getText().toString();

    if(s1.equals("admin") && s2.equals("admin"))
    {
       spinner.setEnabled(false);
    }

}
```